# Where and How to Install Tomcat in Xampp on Mac

Tags: tomcat, xampp

I have installed the Mac version of xampp on my computer and now would like to install Tomcat as well to run Java applications in the sandbox.  Can anyone please help me with installing in Xampp?  I can find no documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat is still not part of the XAMPP package for OSX. The package includes only Apache, FTP (ProFTPD) and MySQL.

You can dowload Tomcat from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi . Setup instructions: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html . OSX specific install how-to: https://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/tomcat8/

Comment: But we can get tomcat in Windows version